# Perl Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion and vice-versa

Tags: perl

I have the question in Perl:
To write a Perl script which will ask the user for a temperature and then ask whether it is to be converted to degree Celius or Fahrenheit. Perform the conversion and display the answer. The equations for temperature conversion are:

```
1) Celsius to Fahrenheit:C=(F-32) x 5/9
2) Fahrenheit to Celsius:F=9C/5 + 32
```

My script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter the temperature: ";
my $temp = <STDIN>;
print "Enter the Conversion to be performed:";
my $conv = <STDIN>;
my $cel;
my $fah;

if ($conv eq 'F-C') {

   $cel = ($temp - 32) * 5/9;
   print "Temperature from $fah degree Fahrenheit is $cel degree Celsius";
}

if ($conv eq 'C-F') {

    $fah = (9 * $temp/5) + 32;
    print "Temperature from $cel degree Celsius is $fah degree Fahrenheit"; 
}
```

After I enter $temp and $conv from the keyboard, blank output will appear.Where am I going wrong? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If other people are looking for it: there's a CPAN module that does this: [Convert::Temperature](https://metacpan.org/module/Convert::Temperature)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the input, you will have a newline character in your variables. Use `chomp` to get rid of it.

Then there will be a second problem - you are using `$fah` or `$cel` in your output statement. This should be the `$temp` variable, otherwise you will get an error like this:

> Use of uninitialized value $cel in concatenation (.) or string at...

Here is the updated code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Enter the temperature: ";
my $temp = <STDIN>;
chomp($temp);
print "Enter the Conversion to be performed:";
my $conv = <STDIN>;
chomp($conv);
my $cel;
my $fah;
if ($conv eq 'F-C')
{
 $cel = ($temp - 32) * 5/9;
 print "Temperature from $temp degree Fahrenheit is $cel degree Celsius";
}
if ($conv eq 'C-F')
{
 $fah = (9 * $temp/5) + 32;
 print "Temperature from $temp degree Celsius is $fah degree Fahrenheit"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't accounting for the new line character that will be in the user input.

Call [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) on each scalar after you assign something from `<STDIN>` to it.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. After I called chomp for both $temp and $conv, I got the required output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `Convert::Pluggable` like so:

```pl
use Convert::Pluggable;

my $c = new Convert::Pluggable;

my $result = $c->convert( { 'factor' => 'someNumber', 'from_unit' => 'C', 'to_unit' => 'F', 'precision' => 'somePrecision', } );
```